# RuntimeException: Buffer not large enough for pixels

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm receiving a Bitmap in byte array through socket and I read it and then I want to set it `os.toByteArray` as `ImageView` in my application. The code I use is:

```
try {
    //bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(result, 0, result.length);
    bitmap_tmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(540, 719, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(os.toByteArray());

    bitmap_tmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
    Log.d("Server",result+"Length:"+result.length);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap_tmp);
        }
    });
    return bmp;
} finally {
}
```

When I run my application and start receiving `Byte[]` and expect that `ImageView` is changed, it's not.

**LogCat** says:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Buffer not large enough for pixels at
android.graphics.Bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer
```

I searched in similar questions but couldn't find a solution to my problem.

Comment: what is your android os version?

Comment: Do the image bytes have the same dimension as your bitmap (540x719)?

Comment: Don't you need to set the buffer size with ByteBuffer.allocate?

Comment: I'm using 4.1.2(API level 16).

Comment: @Henry Yes. The length of the byte[] is 540*719*4.

Comment: @JamesB I tried to allocate the ByteBuffer but it still gives me the same exception.

Comment: How did you allocate it?

Comment: @JamesB I had another error. Now I'm using 
`result = os.toByteArray(); 
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(result.length);
buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(result);` 
and it works but it's too slow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at the source (version 2.3.4_r1, last time Bitmap was updated on Grepcode prior to 4.4) for [Bitmap::copyPixelsFromBuffer()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/graphics/Bitmap.java#Bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer%28java.nio.Buffer%29)

The wording of the error is a bit unclear, but the code clarifies-- it means that your buffer is calculated as not having enough data to fill the pixels of your bitmap.
This is (possibly) because they use the buffer's remaining() method to figure the capacity of the buffer, which takes into account the current value of its position attribute.  If you call rewind() on your buffer before you invoke copyFromPixels(), you might see the runtime exception disappear.  I say 'might' because the ByteBuffer::wrap() method should set the position attribute value to zero, removing the need to call rewind, but judging by similar questions and my own experience resetting the position explicitly may do the trick.

Try

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(os.toByteArray());
buffer.rewind();
bitmap_tmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
```

Comment: Not worked guy. My buffer size = 921600. It is still not enough?

Answer (score 1):

The buffer size should be exactly 1553040B (assuming bitmap's height, width and 32bit to encode each color).