# Android byte array exception?

Tags: android, android-ndk

In android I used ByteBuffer to copy bitmap data, and send it to JNI NDK android. But I am stucking with the same problem again and again,

I had increase the byte buffer size double from the bitmap, but the problem is same as below

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Buffer not large enough for pixels,,,
```

How to solve this?

Comment: I am also facing same issue in one of my project.any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167192/runtimeexception-buffer-not-large-enough-for-pixels

Comment: this was not worked for me, i have already implemented that one ,

Comment: Either you're not at the start of the buffer, or the buffer isn't big enough.  Show how you're sizing the buffer.

Comment: I declared the Bytebuffer size globally with size 124416, and i'm coping just only 62208 data size, After sending data to the JNI C file and pushing the buffer null, but the problem is same